# Can't include Phactory in Symfony2/PHPUnit test

Tags: symfony, phactory

I'm trying to get Phactory working with a Symfony2 project. Here's what I have in one of my unit tests:

```
<?php
namespace VNN\PressboxBundle\Tests\Entity;
namespace VNN\PressboxBundle\Entity;
use VNN\PressboxBundle\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;
use Phactory\Sql\Phactory;

class UserTest extends EntityTest
{
    public function testCreate()
    {   
        Phactory::define('user', array(
            'username' => 'jasonswett',
        )); 
    }   
}
```

The error I'm getting when I try to run that test is this:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Phactory\Sql\Phactory' not found in /Users/jason/Web/pressbox/src/VNN/PressboxBundle/Tests/Entity/UserTest.php on line 12
```

Fair enough. How do I get this file to talk to Phactory? If it helps, I know that the `Phactory` class is defined in `vendor/chriskite/phactory/lib/Phactory/Sql/Phactory.php` and the first few lines of it look like this:

```
<?php

namespace Phactory\Sql;

class Phactory {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the `Phactory` namespace to `autoload.php`.

Also, I prefer to set PHPUnit's `bootstrap` argument to `autoload.php` in `phpunit.xml.dist`:

```xml
<phpunit
    ...
    bootstrap = "autoload.php"
>
```

This works great for Symfony 2.1 projects based on Composer, but I'm not sure about the 2.0 ones.